# ScrollTo fires too early resulting in not scrolling all the way

Tags: javascript, html, angular, scrollto

I am making an Angular application which shows a table with a single tr. This row contains multiple td's which contain data. the table is built up like this:

```
<div class="col" id="TableCol">
    <table id="Table">
      <tbody>
        <tr>
          <td *ngFor="let item of items;">
            <div 
            (click)="ItemSelected(item)" 
            draggable="true" 
            [class.selected]="item.id == selecteditem?.id"
            (dragstart)="dragStart($event, item)" 
            (drop)="dropItem($event, item)" 
            (dragover)="dragoverItem($event, item)">
              {{item.description}}
            </div>
          </td>
        </tr>
      </tbody>
    </table>
  </div>
```

The table is scrollable when it overflows its X value

```
#TableCol{ overflow-x: scroll; }
```

Now i have a function which adds a td at the right side of this tr.
When this function is called an extra td shows up into my table and scrolling works fine.

The thing I want to achieve is that the table automatically scrolls all the way to the right when I add a new td.

I've tried to call this function right AFTER I've added the new item to the items array.

```
this.items.push(item);

scrollRight() {
document.querySelector('#mapLocationTableCol').scrollLeft = 10000;}
```

and

```
scrollRight() {
document.querySelector('#mapLocationTableCol').scrollTo(10000, 0);}
```

Both these give the same result:
They scroll my row all the way to the right except for the last element.

I think this is due to the scrollRight() being called before the table is redrawn.

Anyone have a solution to make it scroll after the table is drawn?

edit: I've made a stackblitz example:

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-d6lm6k

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should monitor the creation of the table cell with `ViewChildren` and the `QueryList.changes` event. In the markup, set a template reference variable on the `td` elements:

```
<td #cells *ngFor="let item of items;">
```

In the code, use `ViewChildren` to get the list of these elements, and subscribe to the `QueryList.changes` event in `ngAfterViewInit`. If a new cell was added, do the scrolling. In the code below, I set a flag to make sure that automatic scrolling is performed only when desired.

```
@ViewChildren("cells") cells: QueryList<ElementRef>;

private shouldScrollRight = false;
...

addItem() {
  this.shouldScrollRight = true;
  this.items.push(item);
}

ngAfterViewInit() {
  this.cells.changes.subscribe((cellList) => {
    if (this.shouldScrollRight) {
      this.shouldScrollRight = false;
      this.scrollRight();
    }
  });
}
```

See [this stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-cq3arm) for a demo.

Comment: hmm.. That was quite an easy solution. Thank You!